# how select multiple rows in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

table is:

city_id  string ,city_name string ,city_country string ,city_coord_lon  string,city_coord_lat string,time string,data_dt string,data_temp_day string,data_temp_min   string,data_temp_max string,data_temp_night string,data_temp_eve string,data_temp_morn string,    data_pressure string,data_humidity string,data_weather_id string,data_weather_main string, data_weather_description string,data_weather_icon string,data_speed string,data_deg string,data_clouds string,data_rain string,data_snow string )
row format delimited fields terminated BY ',' lines;

[image: My table Format]

I want to select all temperature value which lying in city Kathmandu.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select myTable.column1, myTable.column2, .... from myTable where myTable .city_name = 'Kathmandu'
```

(if City_name contains real city names, if no change city_name to same column )